# Embed Views in super view without losing autolayout constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, interface-builder, autolayout

in an ios application, 
I have a custom UITableViewCell with a lot of views in it. I am using auto layout and setup all the constraints as I need.

But now I need to have a main view (in the content view) and put all the other views in it (some sort of a parent view to all).

This is an example of how my cell looks in the interface builder:

[image]

it has all the views setup with the constraints.

I know there is an xcode feature to embed selected views inside a parent view:

[image]

So I select all the view and select to embed them in a view. I get the following:

[image]

**My Problem**

Although the views are embedded correctly in a superview, the autolayout constraint were removed, and now I have to recreate them.

Is there a way I can put all the views inside a superview and have the same autolayout constraints without having to recreate them all? 
Thank you

Comment: You might want to check out http://indiestack.com/2013/12/transplanting-constraints/
I didn't want to set this as an answer because when I tried this method on my own project without success. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in the comments above, this approach works well for me:

[indiestack.com/2013/12/transplanting-constraints](http://www.indiestack.com/2013/12/transplanting-constraints)

In short, the approach is:

1. Give your old superview a restorationId so you can easily identify it in the XML.
2. Open the XIB/Storyboard you are working with in a text editor view.
3. Copy and paste what is currently there into a backup file.
4. Embed your content into a new superview using the storyboard.  Do not set any new constraints yet.
5. Give your new superview a restoration ID so you can easily identify it in the XML.
6. Open up the current storyboard/XIB side by side with the old storyboard/XIB you backed up.
7. Find the old container view in the backed up XML by searching for the restoration ID.  Copy everything inside the `<constraints></constraints>` and `<subviews></subviews>` tags
8. Find the new container view in the current XML and replace the content of its `<constraints></constraints>` and `<subviews></subviews>` tags with the copied content
9. Go into the old XML and copy the ID of the old container.
10. Go into the new XML, and replace the old ID you got from step 9 with the id of the new container everywhere inside the `<constraints></constraints>` you pasted in.
11. Don't forget to add constraints to your new container that match the old container (in my case this was pinning the new container to all the edges of the super view).

Caveat:
This will break any outlets to constraints you may have set up.  Outlets to other things, views, etc... will be fine.

Comment: This is still working pretty well. Only thing different in my case is that I needed to replace the id of the "Safe Area" with an id of the new container view since all the constraint were originally against it, and not the view controller parent view...

Comment: Note: if you have size class variations, you will have to include `<variation>` blocks in your transplanting.

Answer (score 7):

- Select all views
- goto editor -> embed in -> view
- Again select all views
- Add new constraint , pin top, bottom, leading, trailing to 0

[image]

Comment: You're a life saver. I was manually adding in a parent view and having to re-setup all the constraints again. This makes things way easier. Just a slight additional note: when selecting views, don't select the safe area, or root view of the whole hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to just create the constraints of the container view? You don't need to recreate all the constraints.

They are appearing as incorrect because the loosing they parent constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new view at the top level of the xib. Then drag your existing view into it. Existing constraints will still be there. You'll just have to set new constraints up for the embedding.